# Fullcalendar snap to event start/end

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar for events that have arbitrary lengths of minutes), meaning they can have a length of 12:33 in a 5 minutes slot. Is it possible to make the draggable/resized/created event to snap not to the grid but the to the event currently hovered? Meaning if an event finished as 14:23 and I am moving an event over it, I want the dragged one to snap to 14:23 insteaf of 14:25